# What is the reason that jaxb annotations are not extendible?

Tags: java, jaxb

if you take a look on jsr-303 (bean validation) you notice that annotations can be be put on `ANNOTATION_TYPE` in @target like (e.g. `javax.validation.constraints.Min`)

By this the bean validation are easily extended to `@OnlyPositiveNumber`.

in jaxb for Example (a bad one) I could have created `@XmlAlwaysRequiredElement`

Is there a good reason why JAXB annotations like `XmlElement` are not using the same technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you could say "it wasn't done because of X" - it is the way it is, and either the spec leads didn't consider it necessary, or they didn't think of it at all.  Who knows.

However, in the case, I don't really see much need for it. You example concerns data validation, and JAXB is designed to work with XML Schema to do that, rather than doing to validation using annotations.

If we want to have annotation-based validation for JAXB, then it would make more sense to use JSR-303 validations for this, and have the JAXB runtime pick them up and use them, rather than, or in addition to, XML Schema validation.  None of the current implementations do that, though (I think).

Comment: Like always thanks for your answer (which sounds reasonable, I admit). I agree that customized validation is more suitable via JSR-303. I still feel that JAXB lacks extend able components, maybe I don't know about them... BTW: it will be easy to implement your suggestion by hooking afterUnmarshal listener that will validate the object using hibernate validator for example.